# Как можно сделать, чтобы при наведении на каждую фотку появлялась иконка плэй?

Tags: css

[image]

Как можно сделать, чтобы при наведении на каждую фотку появлялась иконка плэй?
Только с индивидуальными ID можно? А полегче вариант?

Comment: > Как можно сделать, чтобы при наведении на каждую фотку появлялась иконка плэй?
Чере css - с помощью псевдокласса hover, с заменой бекграунда (еси реализуется через бекграунд) или с появлением спозиционированного элемента (display: none -> display:block, position:absolute, top: -100px). Можно и через js делать то же самое - события onmouseover, omouseout.

> А полегче вариант?
Что?

Comment: Кажется не так выразился. Знаю что hover'ом, просто когда через класс делаю, при наведении на одну, появляется на всех. Хочу как бы она появлялась на той, на что я навел курсор. Могу конечно задать каждому элементу ID и работать так. Но это долго. Нет ли легкого пути?

Comment: @navi1893, значит, применяете hover на общий контейнер

http://jsfiddle.net/yFqFH/

Comment: не выходит =/

http://jsfiddle.net/XcZjJ/

Comment: @navi1893

    $('.controls img').css({
        'display' : 'none'
    })

эта конструкция ищет все .controls img, странно ожидать чего-то другого

http://jsfiddle.net/XcZjJ/2/

Answer (score 4):

```
img {
  position: relative; // Позиционирование потомков относительно родителя
}

img:hover:before {
  content: url("/images/play.png"); // Путь к вашей иконке.
  z-index: 1; // Изображение на уровень выше.
  position: absolute; // Абсолютно позиционируем.
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%; // Изображение размещено в центре элемента-родителя.
}
```

[Работающий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/3J5gu/4/), только вместо иконки красный квадрат:

```css
.playlist p {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

p:hover:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  content: "";
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="playlist">
  <p id="1"></p>
  <p id="2"></p>
  <p id="3"></p>
  <p id="4"></p>
  <p id="5"></p>
</div>
```